# How could I avoid nested for each in a HTML (LWC component)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, table, nested, for

I'm starting to create a modal like in this picture, but I only got it doing nested `for each` (line 42 and 43 of the .html) for the table. That's not good practice, right? So how could avoid it?

I tried to use `lightning-datatable`, but the cells are selectable and I was not able to disable this function.

[image]

**.js File**

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';

export class Table extends LightningElement {
  @track columns = ['', 'COLUMN 1', 'COLUMN 2', 'COLUMN 3', 'COLUMN 4'];
  @track rows = [1, 2, 3, 4,5];
}
```

**The html file**

````
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
            </button>
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_medium">TITLE</h1>
                <h2 class="slds-text-title">SUB</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-lookup" data-select="multi" data-scope="single" data-typeahead="true">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-p-top_medium slds-p-horizontal_medium slds-m-bottom_small">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                            <button
                                class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right searchButtonStyle">
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:search" variant="bare"
                                    alternative-text="Search" aria-hidden="true" onclick={handleSearch}>
                                </lightning-button-icon>
                            </button>
                            <input type="text" id="lookup" class="slds-input" role="combobox" aria-activedescendant=""
                                aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="lookup-grouped-table-id-1"
                                aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" placeholder="Search..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover"
                        role="listbox" id="lookup-grouped-table-id-1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                                    <th key={col}>
                                        {col}
                                    </th>
                                </template>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                                <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                                    <tr key={row}>
                                        <td key={row} class="slds-text-align_left">
                                            <div key={row} class="slds-form-element__control">
                                                <input type="radio" id={row} value={row} name="default" checked="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td key={row}>
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Seattle, WA">XXX</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td key={row}>
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Seattle, WA">ABC</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td key={row}>
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Seattle, WA">XYZ</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td key={row}>
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Seattle, WA">OPQ</div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </template></template>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close">Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">New Account</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
</template>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rendering a table. This means you have a full matrix of data to render, so this is a valid use of a nested iterator. You could avoid a nested loop with some tricky flex grid stuff, but that's not necessary; the extra layer makes it easier to code and doesn't significantly increase render time

Comment: Thanks! Curiosity: If I wrote it using lightning-datatable, would there be a way to make the cells unselectable?

Comment: @Caroline I'm not sure. You might try disabling online editing, that might work. That said, a proper table implantation might be more legible.